# Is there a way to include DOT but not a Double Integer in Java Regex?

Tags: java, string, split, double

I have

`String prog = "public class HelloWorld {\n" + "public static void main.(String[] args) int b = 0.5 \n"`

(Here the dot(.) after main in the string is purposeful)

Here I need to separate the string as a whole into the below components -

1. public
2. class
3. HelloWorld
4. {
5. public
6. static
7. void
8. main
9. .
10. (
11. String
12. [
13. ]
14. args
15. )
16. int
17. b
18. =
19. 0.5

The numbers and . are just for reference (i.e. 1. , 2. , 11. ). The output must be the components

I've used `split()` with \\s+ and look ahead & look behind assertions for the symbols :-
(+-*/[);].

`String[] words = prog.split("\\\s+|((?<=])|(?=]))|((?<=\\[)|(?=\\[))|((?<=\\()|(?=\\())|((?<=\\))|(?=\\)))|((?<=[-+*/=;.])|(?=[-+*/=;.]))");`

Please excuse for the complexity. Any compression would be appreciated.

It works perfectly fine to give the components, but when trying split main. into main and . while keeping the 0.5 intact, the expression I use ((?<=[-+*/=;.])|(?=[-+*/=;.])) doesn't work.

It separates main. into main and .  but also 0.5 to 0 and . and 5

I need 0.5 to remain as 0.5 , i.e. double retains as double, while splitting main. into main and .

Please provide me with a regex expression to separate period with strings but put double integers intact.

Comment: It is not clear about what are you intending to do here, I mean what you are trying to solve. For regex tweaking there are online tools. Here is one https://regexr.com/

Comment: `public static void main.` <-- the dot after `main` seems dubious to me.  Is that a typo?

Comment: The dot is not a typo, it's on purpose

Comment: I'd like say for another example :- String prog = "System.out.println (0.5) ". I need the output such that there are eight strings :-    System , . , out, . , println, ( , 0.5, )  I want 0.5 as the way it is but when the period is not between the numbers, as a separate string. Hope this clarifies my question. Apologies and thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get close to your expected output by using a formal regex pattern matcher with the following pattern:

```
[\\[\\]{}()+/*-]|[^\\s\\[\\]{}()+/*-]+
```

This pattern either matches a single symbol `[]{}()+/*-` or it matches a non symbol character, which is also not a whitespace character, zero or more times.

```
String prog = "public class HelloWorld {\n" + "public static void main(String[] args) int b = 0.5 \n";
String pattern = "[\\[\\]{}()+/*-]|[^\\s\\[\\]{}()+/*-]+";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(prog);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

This prints:

```
public
class
HelloWorld
{
public
static
void
main
(
String
[
]
args
)
int
b
=
0.5
```

Note that the best way to solve this problem might be to write some sort of Java parser which can tease apart the components as you want.  My solution could easily not work on other Java snippets.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'd like to know if there is a way to use split() to do the same. Also, I'm not really sure about the Java parser you've mentioned.

Comment: Also, in the output I need to get the period (.) after main as shown while keeping the 0.5 as the way it is without splitting.

Comment: Yes, I knew that. It's just included in the string purposefully. It is just to test if we could separate the dot(.) in the output while keeping 0.5 as the way it is. It's not a typo.

Answer (score 0):

To match a literal dot, you need to escape it, so `\.`
For 0.5 , you can use this

```
/^\d*\.?\d*$/
```

Comment: Is there a way to do both ? i.e. parse by a literal dot but not parsing double integers, i.e. separate main. into main and . but leave 0.5 without separating, both at once.